# Itext Table Row , Table Header , Table cell

Tags: itext

I have a requirement to generated the PDF using itext in java

Need to generate the table with 3 rows and 2 columns  , able to create the table.
Country     Langugage
USA         English
Canada       French

When I was trying to read the pdf VIA NVDA Desktop App , the table is not reading the cells properly , say when I want to focus the pointer on Canada , it should the Country - Canada

Following is the code

public class Test {

```
public static final String CSS = "tr { text-align: center; } th { background-color: lightgreen; padding: 3px; } td {background-color: lightblue;  padding: 3px; }";

public static void main(String sunil[])
{
    String pFileName = "Test.pdf";
    String pFilePath = "C:/local/home/dna/pushlive/" + pFileName;
    try {

        FileOutputStream baosPDF = new FileOutputStream(pFilePath);
        com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle pageSize = new com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle(1836, 2376);
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document =  new  com.itextpdf.text.Document(pageSize, 36, 36, 36, 36);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baosPDF);
        writer.setTagged(); 

        document.open();

        PdfPTable bannerTable = new PdfPTable(4);


        document.add(createFirstTable());

        document.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

public static PdfPTable createFirstTable() {
    // a table with three columns
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

    // the cell object
    PdfPCell cell;
    // we add a cell with colspan 3
    //create header cell for first row
    // now we add a cell with rowspan 2


    //add metadata for each cell in the body.


    // we add the four remaining cells with addCell()
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Country"));
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Language"));
    table.addCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("USA")); 
    table.addCell(cell);


    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("English")); 
    table.addCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Canada"));  
    table.addCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("French"));  
    table.addCell(cell);


    //set header row for the table
    table.setHeaderRows(1);

    return table;
}
```

Comment: So there probably is an error in your code. Or probably in  that NVDA Desktop App. As you neither show your code nor share your PDF, how should we tell? And what is that NVDA Desktop App anyways?

Comment: What @mkl says is true: since you don't show us any code, we can't tell you what you are doing wrong. For the file to be accessible, you need to tag the PDF. Did you tag the PDF correctly? If you're using a version of iText prior to iText 5, you are out of luck. If you're using a recent version of iText 5, it might work (but not for older iText 5 versions). With iText 7, we have done major investments in accessibility. Did you read http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/2-creating-pdfa-files-itext

Comment: Following is the code

Comment: My Bad .. NVDA (NonVisual Desktop Access)  ,  It reads the text on the screen in a computerised voice and following is the below link for download 

https://www.nvaccess.org/download/

And Also I have tried the same option with the PDF --> View --> Read Out Load ..  not working in this case also

Jar Version Using:
itextpdf-5.5.9
itext-pdfa-5.5.9
itext-xtra-5.5.9
xmlworker-5.5.9